# Load image from attatchment field to image control in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I have a table [tb_projects] with lots of fields including an attachment field [P_IMAGE]

I also have a form with an Image control [img_project] onto which i want to display an image from the tb_projects table of a specific record.

GlobalData.getProjectSelected this is a function that returns the current project

My code so far:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstAtt As Recordset
Dim sqlSelect As String

sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM [tb_projects] WHERE [PROJECT_ID] = '" & GlobalData.getProjectSelected & "'"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlSelect, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rstAtt = rst.Fields("P_IMAGE").Value

Me.img_project.Picture = rstAtt.Fields("FileData").Value

rst.Close
rstAtt.Close

Set dbs = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
```

This throws me an error saying: The setting for this property is too long

How can i accomplish this without saving the file to %TEMP% and loading the path to the image control? Is this even possible with DAO?

Comment: If you use a bound attachment control, it will automatically display image attachments. Otherwise, I highly recommend storing file paths in DB and loading images with VBA in image control

Comment: A bound image control will also automatically display image attachments. Unfortunately, you must save the file in order to display it in the image control in your function, it doesn't accept raw image data.

Answer (score 0):

the property `Picture` takes a `string` value. The path of the picture to show.

Use the property `PictureData` which takes `Byte Array` of a picture. Make sure your DB field [P_IMAGE] has valid byte array.